# Styling menu bar with left and right navigation button

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I used ng-repeat in following code to create a dynamic menu based on roles selected by user. but after 5 roles I need to have a right navigation button which will actually enable next 5 roles and when next 5 roles enabled , it will have left navigation and right navigation to display previous menus and next menus.I attached image of what I am getting and what I am expecting. I missing somewhere some point, Need assistance.

My output :
[image: My output]

Actual needed one :
[image: Actual needed one]

HTML:

```
    <div class="Allmenus">
 <aside class="myextensionbar" ng-if="moreRoles=true">
       <ul class="mynewul">

           <li class="myli"><a href ng-click="showPreviousRole()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a></li>   

                    </ul>
                    </aside>
    <section class="mytopmenu">
    <ul class="myul nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="myli" ng-repeat="role in roles track by $index" 
      ng-class="{active:isSelected($index)}">
    <a href ng-click="displaySelectedRole(role, $index)">{{role}}</a></li>
</ul>
</section>
    <aside class="myextensionbar" ng-if="moreRoles=true">
   <ul class="mynewul">

       <li class="myli"><a href ng-click="showMoreRole()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a></li>   

                </ul>
                </aside>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.showMoreRole =function(){

    for(var i=0; i<5;i++){ 
        console.log($scope.displayrole[i]);
        $scope.showExtensionBar = false;
        if($scope.displayrole[i]=="Actor"){
            $scope.getActor();
        }

        else if($scope.displayrole[i]=="Director"){

              $scope.getDirector();
        }
        else if($scope.displayrole[i]=="MusicDirector"){

            $scope.getMusicDirector();
                }

         else if($scope.displayrole[i]=="Singer"){

            $scope.getSinger();
         }

        else if($scope.displayrole[i]=="Lyricist"){
            $scope.getLyricist();
                }
        else if($scope.displayrole[i]=="Dialogue"){
            $scope.getDialogue();
                }
        else if($scope.displayrole[i]=="Model"){
            $scope.getModel();
       }
         else if($scope.displayrole[i]=="GraphicDesigner"){
            $scope.getGraphicDesigner();
                }
         else if($scope.displayrole[i]=="Screenplay"){
            $scope.getScreenplay();
                }
         else if($scope.displayrole[i]=="Dialogue"){
            $scope.getDialogue();
                }
         else if($scope.displayrole[i]=="BackgroundMusic"){
            $scope.getBackgroundMusic();
                }
    }
    };
```

Display Selected Roles:

```
   $scope.displaySelectedRole = function(role, index) {

       $scope.indexValue = index;
       $scope.roleName = role;

       if(role == "Actor") {
           $scope.getActorInfo();
       } else if (role == "Director") {
           $scope.getDirectorInfo();
       } else if (role == "Singer") {
           $scope.getSingerInfo();
       } else if (role == "Lyricist") {
           $scope.getLyricistInfo();
       } else if (role == "MusicDirector") {
           $scope.getMusicDirectorInfo();
       } else if (role == "StandupComedian") {
           $scope.getStandupComedianInfo();
       } else if (role == "Model") {
           $scope.getModelInfo();
       } else if (role == "Cinematographer") {
           $scope.getCinematographerInfo();
       } else if (role == "Photographer") {
           $scope.getPhotographerInfo();
       } else if (role == "ScriptWriter") {
           $scope.getScriptWriterInfo();
       } else if (role == "Choreographer") {
           $scope.getChoreographerInfo();
       } else if (role == "Editor") {
           $scope.getEditorInfo();
       } else if (role == "CostumeDesigner") {
           $scope.getCostumeDesignerInfo();
       }
```

Comment: can you create a plunker demo?

Comment: Yes I will create a plunker and share